# How to initialize a IMimeMessage object from IStream

Tags: c++, com, mime

Given an empty MimeMessage created with e.g. MimeOleCreateMessage function, how can I initialize it from an IStream / data buffer, which contains the complete message text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong IMimeMessage returned by MimeOleCreateMessage supports IPersistStream stream then you have Load & Save methods.

Comment: Thank you. Already found out the way myself. Turned out to be piece of cake :).